# How to use the IN operator with uuid - Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-orm

How to use the IN operator with uuid - Django?

Model

```
class Client(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    nome    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Subscription(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    vencimento = models.DateField()
    client = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

View

```
 clients = Client.objects.filter(nome__icontains=q).values_list('pk', flat=True)
 subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(client_id__in=clients)
```

I tried using this to convert and it still does not work.

```
clients = [str(o) for o in clients]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you.

I also tried this

```
subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(client__nome__icontains=q)
```

Query

```
SELECT "app_subscription"."id", "app_subscription"."vencimento","app_subscription"."client_id", "app_subscription"."created_at", "app_subscription"."updated_at" FROM "app_subscription" INNER JOIN "cad_client" ON ("app_subscription"."client_id" = "cad_client"."id") WHERE "cad_client"."nome" LIKE %marcelo% ESCAPE '\'
```

ERROR

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying
>   = uuid
>
> operator does not exist: character varying = uuid LINE 1:
>   ...client" ON ("app_subscriptions"."client_id" = "clien...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might
>   need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Share any errors if any.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to list:

```
clients_list = list(Client.objects.filter(nome__icontains=q).values_list('pk', flat=True))
subscriptions = subscription.objects.filter(client__id__in=clients_list)
```

Comment: Which is the field name cliente of client

Comment: try: subscription.objects.filter(client__id__in=clients_list)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your model does not contain the `nome` filed. So, assuming it does, your query returns a queryset. So, for the `IN` to work, what you want to pass in is a list.

```
clients = Client.objects.filter(nome__icontains=q).values_list('pk', flat=True)
clients = list(clients)
subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(client_id__in=clients)
```

Comment: clients = list(clients) does not Work. Yes, nome

Comment: There doesn't seem to be the `nome` field in your `Client` model above.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use two queries, or even a subquery, here. A simple related lookup is what you need.

```
subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(client__nome__icontains=q)
```

But note that your actual error, as others have pointed out, is probably because your Client model does not appear to contain a `nome` field.

Comment: Did not work *how*? What did you see? And if the field exists, please *edit your question* to show it. Please ensure you post the actual code; if that part of the model is inaccurate, there may be other errors that would change the answer.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Postgres. SELECT "app_subscription"."id", "app_subscription"."vencimento","app_subscription"."client_id", "app_subscription"."created_at", "app_subscription"."updated_at" FROM "app_subscription" INNER JOIN "cad_client" ON ("app_subscription"."client_id" = "cad_client"."id") WHERE "cad_client"."nome" LIKE %marcelo% ESCAPE '\'

Answer (score 0):

```
class Subscription(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    vencimento = models.DateField()
    client = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This column in the database was not of the uuid type. He was with Varchar.

So it was not possible to compare.

Just change the type of the Varchar column to uuid in the database.

Thank you all for your attention.

```
client = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```